# Select with Left Function Condition SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, case

Can anyone help with this query?

```
SELECT        TOP (200) Material, Plant, StorLocation, Batch, 
LEFT(Batch, 1),
CASE WHEN LEFT(Batch, 1) <> '0' THEN 
    Batch  
ELSE 
    CONVERT(INT, Batch)
END AS BATCH, 

MaterialDescription, SLDays, Days, SLEDBBD, Unrestricted, BUn, Location, Status
FROM            ZMB5M
WHERE BATCH = '67918688Q0'
```

But it return an error :

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '67918688Q0' to data type int.
```

Batch is in nvarchar, and i want to remove data in batch that have some '0' in start of data
Thanks..

Comment: '67918688Q0' 'Q' is clearly not a digit

Comment: Your query and problem statement do not agree.  Do you want to cast the column as an integer, or remove values which begin with a zero?

Comment: My batch data is like this :
27835000,
0046417300,
391189,
70860L,
60841L,
4500276703,
TAX17G1-01,
A010H6B016,
A010H7S005

Comment: yes @TimBiegeleisen , i want remove values which begin with a zero. Remove the '0' values

Comment: Aggred with @MitchWheat '67918688Q0' is not a digit if you want to convert this get substring that would be '67918688' then you can convert this in int.